# Asset Price - Simple Moving Average Script

Tags: pine-script, moving-average

I'm trying to find the deviation between the current price and the simple moving average.
My attempted code is below, error message "Could not find function or function reference 'sma'."
Not sure why that is given sma is a Pine Script function, any help would be appreciated.

```
indicator("Divergence")
myMA = sma(close,50)
Divergence = (myMA-close)
plot(Divergence, color=color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `version 5` new namespaces have been introduce. For technical indicators, there is `ta` now. So, try `ta.sma(close, 50)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for reference code now using below.

```
study(title="Divergence v3", overlay=true)

// Calculate moving averages
TF = input(title="TF", type=resolution,defval="D")
fastMA = sma(close, 20)
Divergence = close/fastMA
Mid=1
L= security(tickerid, 'D', low)
H= security(tickerid, 'D', high)
Low=  L/fastMA
High=  H/fastMA

// Plot values
plot(series=Divergence, color=orange, linewidth=1)
plot(series=Mid, color=white, linewidth=1)
plot(series=High, color=red, linewidth=1)
plot(series=Low, color=green, linewidth=1)
```